# Can Core NLP be used to identify idioms and phrasal verbs?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have a corpus containing a large number of sentences and I would like to be able to filter its sentences based on a word, phrasal verb, or idiom.

For example, when filtering on "turn", sentences like these would be returned:

```
Turn left!
It is my turn now.
```

However, it would not return:

```
Turn the radio off now!
```

Instead, filtering on "turn off" would return this sentence. Could I use Core NLP do do this? I processed the sentence "Turn the radio off now!" using http://corenlp.run/ but the resulting outputs suggest that maybe this isn't possible. Perhaps this is too complicated a sentence and that Core NLP would indeed be useful in the case of more straight forward sentences like "Turn off the radio now!" For example, there is a compound.prt dependency between the verb and preposition in this case.

Also if you think another tool would be more suitable please mention it. I'm am interested primarily in Spanish at the moment.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I would indeed go along the lines of using dependency parse graphs. If there is a preposition/particle that has this compound.prt-type dependency on your verb, then exclude it from your results. (If I try "Turn off the radio" vs. "Turn the radio off", I get this compound.prt relation in both cases, so that doesn't stop you from using this approach)